# Customize tabview titlebar

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcode, xcode-storyboard

I want to display title of my each view in tabview at the top with the text being left aligned, currently when I toggle the top titlebar in storyboard I get something like this:

[image: storyboard view titlebar]

But when I run my app the title isn't displayed like this, how do I show this when the app is running??

### Update 1:

I am able to show the title bar by embedding the tabview controller inside a navigationview controller. Now the only issue I have is setting the alignment of the title to left.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote a custom extension to `UINavigationItem` that sets the title left aligned:

```
extension UINavigationItem {
    
    // MARK: Use this Method for setting up title for Any Controller *ALWAYS*
    public func setTitle(_ title: String, leftInset: CGFloat = -5) {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.text = title
        label.textAlignment = .left
        let customView = UIView()
        customView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        customView.backgroundColor = .clear
        label.textAlignment = .left
        customView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: 0)

        if #available(iOS 12, *) {
            label.frame.origin = CGPoint(x: leftInset + 3, y: -13)
        } else {
            label.frame.origin = CGPoint(x: leftInset, y: -13)
        }
        customView.addSubview(label)
        customView.layoutIfNeeded()
        customView.sizeToFit()
        label.layoutIfNeeded()
        label.sizeToFit()
        customView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = true
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = true
        titleView = customView
    }
}
```

Add this in each `UIViewController` that is used in the tabview:

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        tabBarController?.navigationItem.setTitle("Sample", leftInset: 12)
    }
```

The tabviewcontroller has to be embedded inside navigationviewcontroller for this to work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
navigationItem.largeTitleDisplayMode = .always
navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true
```

Comment: It still doesn't display the title either.